# Babel module resolver doesn't work as expected (node + typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs, eslint, babel-plugin-module-resolver

In my node project, I use **`babel-plugin-module-resolver`** to have relative paths.

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "strict": true,     
    "noEmit": true,                    
    "esModuleInterop": true,                 
    "skipLibCheck": true,                    
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "constants/*": ["constants/*"],
      "data/*": ["data/*"],
      "database/*": ["database/*"],
      "enums/*": ["enums/*"],
      "features/*": ["features/*"],
      "@library/*": ["library/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

***.eslintrc***

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {}
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": ["warn", "always"],
    "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
    "max-len": ["warn", 150],
    "no-console": 1,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": [
      "warn", {
        "ignoreParameters": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

***.babelrc***

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [ 
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "config": "./src/config",
          "constants": "./src/constants",
          "data": "./src/data",
          "enums": "./src/enums",
          "features": "./src/features",
          "library": "./src/library",
          "middleware": "./src/middleware",
          "utils": "./src/utils"
        }
      }
    ] 
  ]
}
```

when I import files, it doesn't display any errors. Can move to the specific file by clicking on the import path. But when it complies, it give the following error.[image]

how to fix this issue??

Comment: Your tsconfig "paths" and babel config "alias" fields don't seem to match. What happens if you edit your entry in `.babelrc` for the library folder to add the `@`? `"@library": "./src/library",` Is it only imports from `@library` that have an issue, or are there other problematic imports as well?

Comment: See https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/138 for a lengthy discussion about `ts-node` and `paths`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your TS config file's `paths` and Babel config file's `alias` fields don't match. Try prefixing `@` on your problematic imports, as what @jered pointed out in the question comments.

You may also see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/138 for the long discussion regarding `ts-node` and `paths`, as per @pasi said.